# Java S3 API: Files not appearing correctly in S3 browser

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm using [this S3 library](https://github.com/EMCECS/ecs-object-client-java) to store files into S3 bucket.

Here is the code:

**DocumentService.java**

```
    /**
     * Persists document information in Object store
     *
     * @param documentDto document upload data
     * @return id of uploaded document
     * @throws GenericException on error
     */
    @Transactional
    public UUID uploadDocument(DocumentDto documentDto) throws GenericException {
        validationService.validateAndThrowException(documentDto);

        String uuid = randomUUID().toString()
        MultipartFile documentFile = documentDto.getFile();
        String documentRefKey = "SFI_" + currentDate() + "/" + uuid + "/";

        // Store the document in s3 bucket
        s3Client.putObject(createPutDocumentFileRequest(documentFile, documentRefKey));

        return uuid;
    }

    /**
     * Creates put request for object store.
     *
     * @param document document
     * @param documentRefKey document reference key
     * @return put object request
     */
    private PutObjectRequest createPutDocumentFileRequest(MultipartFile document, String documentRefKey) {
        S3ObjectMetadata metadata = new S3ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.addUserMetadata("fileName", document.getFileName());
        metadata.setContentType(document.getFileType());
        PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, documentRefKey, document.getInputStream());
        req.withObjectMetadata(metadata);

        return req;
    }
```

However, if I look into my bucket, this is how it looks:
[image]

No clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured this one out by myself. The real trick is to include the full file name in the `key`.
[image]

In order to debug the issue, I looked into all the properties and meta info of a file that I manually upload via S3 and matched it with a file that's uploaded programmatically.
Which led to the discovery of the mismatch in `key` reference.

I'm surprised that it wasn't mentioned clearly in the documentation. Here's the fixed code:

```
    /**
     * Persists document information in Object store
     *
     * @param documentDto document upload data
     * @return id of uploaded document
     */
    @Transactional
    public UUID uploadDocument(DocumentDto documentDto) {
        validationHandler.validate(documentDto);

        String uuid = randomUUID().toString()
        MultipartFile documentFile = documentDto.getFile();
        String documentRefPath = "SFI_" + currentDate() + "/" + uuid + "/";

        // Store the converted document in s3 bucket
        s3Client.putObject(createPutDocumentFileRequest(documentFile, documentRefPath));

        return uuid;
    }


    /**
     * Creates put request for object store.
     *
     * @param targetFile document file
     * @param documentRefPath document reference key
     * @return put object request
     */
    private PutObjectRequest createPutDocumentFileRequest(MultipartFile documentFile, String documentRefPath) {
        String fileName = documentFile.getFileName();
        String key = documentRefPath + fileName; // <-- the missing puzzle piece

        S3ObjectMetadata metadata = new S3ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.addUserMetadata("fileName", fileName);
        metadata.setContentType(documentFile.getFileType());
        PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, documentFile);
        req.withObjectMetadata(metadata);

        return req;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, probably in the `currentDate` method, in addition to providing a date pattern like `ddMMyyyy`, it seems that you are including a `/` character between the date and the UUID when constructing your `documentRefKey` S3 object key. It will look like the following:

```
SFI_11022021/<the generated uuid>
```

When you put this object in your S3 bucket, AWS interprets that it should create a "folder like" structure, splitting the information by the `/` character:

```
SFI_11022021
    <the generated uuid>
```

According to the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html), given, for instance, the keys `s3-dg.pdf` and `Development/Projects.xls`, among others:

> The console uses the key name prefixes (`Development/`, `Finance/`, and `Private/`) and delimiter (`'/'`) to present a folder structure. The `s3-dg.pdf` key does not have a prefix, so its object appears directly at the root level of the bucket. If you open the `Development/` folder, you see the `Projects.xlsx` object in it.

> - Amazon S3 supports buckets and objects, and there is no hierarchy. However, by using prefixes and delimiters in an object key name, the Amazon S3 console and the AWS SDKs can infer hierarchy and introduce the concept of folders.

Comment: @saran3h Could be the problem the one described in the answer? It would be great if you could include the `currentDate` source code in your question.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, and your guess is correct. For OP, check for created objects/folders on root. S3 has some tricky protocol, it represents folders on GUI but in reality it has no conscience of what a folder is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment @aran, and for the clarification. Yes, I totally agree with you, I think it is in some way related to the folder like structure created by S3 based on the object name provided. Thank you again!!

Comment: @jccampanero I figured it out!
It has nothing to do with the folder structure actually, The requirement is that we need the folder like structure on S3 and we can easily do that via tools like `S3 browser`. 
The trick is to include the full file name in the `key`. It doesn't matter what kind of key are you making. 
I'm really surprised why it's not explicitly mentioned in the documentation.
Check the full answer.

Comment: It is great @saran3h, I am very happy to hear that you figured out the problem. Please, if possible, for future reference for people seeing the question, to avoid confusion, it would be great if you could clarify in it that you really need to include the actual filename in your objects.